# Python regex removing duplicated names

Tags: python, regex

I have a `Series` of names. If a name is repeated, I'd like to have only one.

```
John Smith
David BrownDavid Brown
```

I'd like to have output

```
John Smith
David Brown
```

I found ways to use `'\b(\w+)( \1\b)+'` to catch the white space between names and keep the second one with `r'\1'`. However, in my case, there is no whitespace. Does that mean I need to compare strings character by character to find duplicates? Is there any simpler way ?

Comment: You could try normalizing the name (removing whitespaces and have it all be upper or lower case) and then check  if name[:len(name)/2] == name[len(name)/2:] ? Or could you have extra trash characters? The regex should work too if you normalize this (\b(\w+)(\1\b)+)

Comment: for second line regex is ` (\w+ .+?)\1+ `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a non-greedy modifier(`?`) to test the words to find all the dupilcates optionally:

```
\b(\w+? \w+?)\1*\b
```

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/hbyyJW/1)

---

You may also add another name section to support [middle names](https://regex101.com/r/UDXuxR/1) such as:

```
\b(\w+? \w+?(?: \w+?)?)\1*\b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\b(.+?)\1\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tf7vSc/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\1` - Same value as in Group 1
- `\b` - a word boundary

In Pandas, you can use

```py
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace(r'\b(.+?)\1\b', r'\1', regex=True)
```